# Installing Intel GM965/GL960 secondary graphics controller driver on OpenIndiana

Tags: solaris, intel-graphics, openindiana

I'm trying to get OpenIndiana Hipster build running on an HP 6910p, but the secondary graphics controller is not working.

The primary driver is working using the i915 driver as part of the `xorg-video-intel` package, but the secondary driver shows `unk` in the driver utility.

The PM965/GM965 MEI controller, and the KT controller are also not working.

Is there an existing binary package which supports these devices, or is there any documentation on installing a compatible driver from source?

This laptop has previously run Debian 7, under which all these devices were working properly, however this is my first attempt at installing OpenIndiana on this machine.

Any advice would be appreciated.